# How to use File.Encrypt from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, security, iis, encryption

I have a simple C# ASP.NET MVC app (on Windows Server 2012 R2 & IIS 8.5) for uploading files to a server.  I would like to automatically encrypt these files using File.Encrypt(path-to-file), but I get

```
System.IO.IOException occurred
 HResult=-2146499771
 Message=The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must 
 be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be 
 configured to allow delegation.
```

IIS is running under the default IIS_IUSRS account, which has "Full Control" rights to the folder in question.

**What I am trying to accomplish is a simple Web app where sensitive files can be uploaded by clients, which then can be accessed by authorized users only via the Web app** (with no direct access via the file system, since only the encrypting user account can decrypt the files).

I realize that this solution has shortcomings, but so does public / private key based solution (you get stuck with the problem of where to securely store the private key for decryption).  What I am primarily interested is a solution to my specific scenario.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by creating a user (with minimal rights and a strong password) specifically for the app pool and using it as the App Pool Identity.

I originally wanted to avoid doing this (I thought it would be less secure), but according to Microsoft's "Security Best Practices for IIS 8" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635855.aspx), it is not a problem:

*Using a custom identity account is acceptable, but be sure to use a different account for each application pool*